# Facebook application permissions issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have Facebook application with `publish_actions` and `user_photos` permissions. Those permissions are verified by Facebook and I see them as verified on the application management (status and review), but when I am debugging my application, I don't see the `publish_actions` permission on the session object. I am using `Facebook SDK 3.0.2`. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the permissions have been approved by Facebook just means that you can ask for them. You still have to ask the user if they want to give you that permission. And the user can choose not to give you permission to it.

Answer (score 0):

As per Facebook V2.0 you need to create test application of your main application and add some test user and tester for check facebook  API V2.0

Comment: Only if I create test application and test user I can add publish_actions permission?

Comment: yes but for debugging purpose only before publish application you must verified by facebook

Comment: My app is verified by facebook as I see on the management page